# Como buscar subcadenas exspecificas en una cadena en Angular 8?

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript

Estoy realizando un buscador utilizando Angular 8 y el metodo Apply Filter, la busqueda en general va bien pues como sabemos se hace una comparacion entre el metodo filter y los datos que traemos, en este caso por ejemplo de una tabla. El problema radica en que si yo tengo, por ejemplo, el nombre "Cesar Camacho Diaz" y tecleo en el input "Cesar Camacho" si regresa el resultado al front end, pues si va cocordando lo ingresado con lo que existe en la cadena de alguna fila, ahora bien, si yo llego a poner "Cesar Diaz", por oviedad, ya no me lo trae.

Entonces la pregunta es, como puedo hacer que me traiga "Cesar Camacho Diaz" aun si yo pongo "Cesar Diaz"?

Eh estado dandole vueltas pero no encuentro la manera.

mi codigo HTML es:

```
<mat-form-field>
                <input matInput autocomplete="off" maxlength="256" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)">
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 100%;border-radius: 15px;margin-top: 30px;">


            <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;align-items: center;background-color:#3c7ab6;color: white;border-right: 1px white solid;border-radius: 15px 0 0 0">Nombre </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nombre}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;align-items: center;background-color:#3c7ab6;color: white;border-right: 1px white solid">Email</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="rol">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;align-items: center;background-color:#3c7ab6;color: white;border-right: 1px white solid">Rol</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rol}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="foros">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;align-items: center;background-color:#3c7ab6;color: white;border-right: 1px white solid">Foros Activos</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Foros</mat-label>
                <mat-select [formControl]="toppings">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let dato of element.optionsForos" [value]="dato.val" disabled hidden>
                <p style="color: black"><i class="material-icons" *ngIf="dato.val=='True'" style="color:darkgreen">done</i>
                <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="dato.val=='False'" style="color: red">clear</i>{{dato.label}}</p>
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field></td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="editar">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;align-items: center;background-color:#3c7ab6;color: white;border-right: 1px white solid" >Editar</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><button *ngIf="element.rol =='Administrador'" style="color:#0046af;font-size: 20px;border: none;background-color:transparent;" (click)="openModalEdit()">
                 <i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>
                 <button *ngIf="element.rol =='Super Administrador'" style="color:#0046af;font-size: 20px;border: none;background-color:transparent;opacity:0.7;" (click)="openModalEdit()" disabled>
                 <i class="material-icons">edit</i></button> 
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="eliminar">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align:center;align-items: center;background-color:#3c7ab6;color: white;padding-right: 8px;border-radius: 0 15px 0 0" >Eliminar</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="padding-right:8px"><button *ngIf = "element.rol == 'Administrador'" style="border: none;background-color: transparent;"><i *ngIf="element.estatus_usuario; else reactivacion" class="fas fa-user-check" style="color: #00FF00;
              font-size: 18px;" (click)="cambiaEstatusUsuario(element,element.email)" ></i>
              <ng-template #reactivacion><i class="fas fa-user-slash" style="color: gray;font-size: 18px;" (click)="cambiaEstatusUsuario(element,element.email)" ></i></ng-template></button>
              <button *ngIf = "element.rol == 'Super Administrador'" style="border: none;background-color: transparent;" disabled>
              <i class="fas fa-user-slash" style="color: gray;font-size: 18px;opacity:0.7;"></i></button>
              </td>
            </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
```

mi codigo TS es:

```
  public async obtenerUsuarios(){

    let data;
    this.tablaUsuarios = await this.forosServicio.getUsuarios(data);
    this.tablaUsuarios = this.transfromData(this.tablaUsuarios);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.tablaUsuarios);

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string): boolean => {
      console.log(data);
      const dataStr = Object.keys(data).reduce((currentTerm: string, key: string) => {
        return (currentTerm + (data as { [key: string]: any })[key] + '◬');
      }, '').normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase();



      const transformedFilter = filter.trim().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase();

      return dataStr.includes(transformedFilter);
    }

    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes convertir tus cadenas de texto a un arreglo de palabras para facilitar la búsqueda utilizando funciones del `Array.prototype` como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
let name = "Cesar Camacho Diaz".split(" ");
let query = "Cesar Diaz".split(" ");

let matches = query.every((item) => name.includes(item));
```

Aqui la función [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) nos dice si todas las palabras que están en el query son parte de el nombre al cual estamos comparando.

Dicho esto podemos decir que dados los siguientes inputs

- "Cesar"
- "Camacho"
- "Diaz"
- "Diaz Camacho"
- "Camacho Diaz Cesar"

O cualquier combinación de las primeras tres palabras nos dará como resultado `true`.

> En este ejemplo no tome en cuenta la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, acentos, ni errores búsqueda